# How can I create a class that saves ArrayList with data references?

Tags: java, arraylist, extends, txt2tags

I have a 30 mb txt document with information of this type (In it, first there is the date, time, number of millionths of a second, 3 prices separated by ";" and a transaction)
File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ky0EM75xvDXdHBcFnZYjq7D9FwKy50M/view?usp=sharing

20200429 050000 2500000;8843;8841.75;8843;1

20200429 050000 5740000;8843;8841.75;8843;1

20200429 050000 5740000;8843.25;8841.75;8843.25;1

Each of the data is being stored in a class called "Dato" and there is a data collection "ColeccionDatos" in which each of the data is referenced, however, when creating the instances and trying to read the file "NQ20200429 -30.txt "which contains all the information, a Java.util.MismatchException error occurs.
I have tried for a long time and cannot solve it, I would appreciate your help. Here is the code.

```
   public class Dato
{
    private String fecha;
    private String hora;
    private int diezmill;
    private double last;
    private int transaccion;

    public Dato (String fecha, String hora, double last, int trans){
        this. fecha = fecha;
        this. hora = hora;
        this. last = last;
        this. transaccion = transaccion;
    }

    public String getFecha(){
        return this.fecha;
    }

    public String getHora () {
        return this.hora;
    }

    public int getDiezmill () {
        return this. diezmill;
    }

    public double getLast () {
        return this. last;
    }

    public int getTransaccion () {
        return this.transaccion;
    }

    public String toString () {
        String ret = "";
        ret += fecha + "";
        ret += hora + "";
        ret += diezmill + "";
        ret += last + "";
        ret += transaccion + "";
        return ret;
    }
}
```

//The code for the second class is

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ColeccionDatos
{
    protected ArrayList <Dato> al;

    public ColeccionDatos () {
        al = new ArrayList <> ();
    }

    public void leerActivo (String NombreActivoNQ) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner archivo = new Scanner (new File (NombreActivoNQ)); //In this line the file is processed
        while (archivo.hasNextLine()){
            String linea = archivo.nextLine();   
            linea = linea.replace (";", " ");
            Scanner sl = new Scanner (linea);
            String fecha = sl.next();
            String hora = sl.next();
            int diezmill = sl.nextInt();
            double bid =sl.nextDouble();
            double ask = sl.nextDouble(); //this line throws the exception
            double last = sl.nextDouble();
            int transaccion = sl.nextInt();
            Dato d = new Dato (fecha, hora, last, transaccion);
            al.add(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the exception stacktrace also

Comment: Please indicate which line of the Java code is throwing the exception (eg add a `// This Line throws the exception.` comment) .   Also show the line from the file that is being processed.

Answer (score 0):

*You have made a mistake in Dato constructor it should be `this. transaccion = trans;` instead of `this. transaccion = transaccion;`*

Can you please share your NQ20200429 -30.tx file as I ran your code with the given examples and I didn't encounter Java.util.MismatchException error maybe there is some problem with the input file

Comment: Ok, how can I share the file? (I am new here)

Comment: Done, I appreciate your patience :)

Comment: can you share the stacktrace and mention which line gives an error